# How is this lemma for proposition formulas used in this Theorem and what is a statementvariable exactly?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

We have Statements that are either true or false: eg. $4=0$

We have Statement variables that are either true or false, their value is assigned beforehand: e.g. : $A$

We have Proposition formulas that contain finitely many statement variables which are combined with Logical Operators, after assigning each Statement variable a truth value it becomes a statement:
 $A$ and $A\wedge B$ and  are Proposition formulas for example.

[image]

We use this Lemma to prove the equivalence of a set of pairs of Proposition-formulas. One of those pairs is $(A\Rightarrow B,\neg B\Rightarrow \neg A)$. This is the proof as stated in the script [image: rules]

Can somebody expalin me how the Lemma $1.9$ is used here?

A example for contraposition would be, alternative definitions of injectivity:

$f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$ is equivalent to $x\neq y \Rightarrow f(x)\neq f(y)$

So $f(x)=f(y)$ would be $A$ in this case, i.e. it is not a statement but a statement variable. Can somebody explain me what again what are the conditions for an Expression t be a statement variable?

Comment: What is not clear ? The Lemma states that two formulas with the same "set" of statement variables are equivalent iff... Then you have to consider two formulas having $A,B$ as only statement variables. What are all possible assignments of truth values to $A,B$ ? Those listed in the truth table. Now you have to check that the two formulas to be proved equivalent (two rightmost columns) have the same truth value in each row.

Comment: In propositional calculus, a *statement variable* $A,B,...$ is a variable that stands for a statement. If we replace into $A \to B$ the statement variables $A,B$ with Mathematical statements like $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x=y$ respectively, we get the Mathematical formula $f(x) =f(y) \to x=y$.

Comment: You should cite your sources appropriately. In this case, the source the image displays. This gives credit where due and helps people help you because they can look up the resource as well. It's also a good habit to get into for cases where it is a matter of academic integrity or legality.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't understand the "iff" part in the lemma, wouldn't it be sufficient to say if $\phi(A_1,...,A_n)$ and $\varphi(A_1,...,A_n)$ have the same truth value for all possible assignments of truthvaslues on $A_1,...,A_n$ then $\phi(A_1,...,A_n)$ and $\varphi(A_1,...,A_n)$ are equivalent. Why does the lemma also prove the other side, i.e. if $\phi(...)$ and $\varphi(...)$ are equivalent then $\phi(...),\varphi(...)$ have the same truthvalue for all possible assignment of truthvalues to $A_1,...,A_n$ what is the purpose here of showing the other side?

Comment: @DerekElkins the source is http://www.math.lmu.de/~philip/publications/lectureNotes/philipPeter_LinearAlgebra1.pdf

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if we replace the statemant variable with a mathematical statement does it become a statement? But how do we know whether the mathematical statement $f(x)=f(y)$ is true or not?

Comment: $(A \to B)$ is equivalent to $(\lnot B \to \lnot A)$ (see truth table). Thus, for every pair of mathematical statements that we use in place of $A$ and $B$, like e.g. $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x=y$, the corresponding formulas : $f(x)=f(y) \to x=y$ and $\lnot (x=y) \to \lnot (f(x)=f(y))$ will be equivalent.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In a previous comment of yours you said $A,B$ are variables that stand for Statements. But $f(x)=f(y)$ is not a Statement because we don't know whether $f(x)=f(y)$ is true or false. Can you help me to clarify this? Also the Lemma says: two formulas with the same "set" of statement variables are equivalent $A$ iff $\iff$ they have the same truth value for all possible assignements of truthvalues to the statementvariables $B$. So if we show $B$ (truthtable) which we did in the proof (see above) then $A$ follows. What's the Purpose of showing $A\Rightarrow B$ in the Lemma?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I hope you can help me with this problem so I don't have to open a new question, maybe you can also suggest what I can do to understand the solution. My problem is that we have propositional formulas on the one hand and statements on the other side. A propositional formula contains statement variables like $A,B$ and logical operators, and if $A,B$ are substituted with statements the propositional formula becomes a statement. If I look at $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$ is this then a statement or a propositional formula? I think it is a statement because we have substituted $A,B$

Comment: but this would mean that $f(x)=f(y)$ and $x=y$ are statements too. How do we know whether $f(x)=f(y)$ is true or  with other word why is this something like "Every dog is an animal"?

Comment: I think $f(x)=f(y)\Rightarrow x=y$ is a propositional formula because $f(x)=f(y)$ is an object that can either be true or wrong but then we haven't substituted $A$ and $B$ not with statements, i.e. objects that are either true or wrong but with objects that either *can* be true or wrong